# Greatest value from 3 joined columns from 3 different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried to solve this query issue but didn't find a working solution.

**Insight into my database relations and structures:**

I have 3 tables 2 of them have a foreign ID key pointing to the native ID key from the 3th tabel, all three of the tables have dates in the sql datetime value.

**Insight in my goal:**

I want to find the latest date from those three dates, and output that single value in php. In order to achieve that goal I joined the three tables and used the built-in sql greatest function in order to retrieve the latest datum on the three selected columns.

**Insight in my sql code:**

```
SELECT GREATEST(Reacties.datum, Deelnemers.datum ,Skirms.submit_datum) 
FROM Skirms 
INNER JOIN Deelnemers ON Skirms.ID = Deelnemers.skirms_fk 
INNER JOIN Reacties ON Skirms.ID = Reacties.skirms_fk 
WHERE Skirms.ID = 1
```

**Problem with above code**

When executing the above query it unfortunately returns me no value.

Comment: If any of 2 child rows can be missing then you need LEFT JOIN. Otherwise I see no problem in the query, check your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might return multiple rows. You can apply MAX before the GREATEST:

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(Reacties.datum), MAX(Deelnemers.datum) ,MAX(Skirms.submit_datum))
```

But if you simply want the latest date from three tables there's no need to join those tables, select each maximum date and then the maximum of those:

```
select max(maxDate)
from
 ( SELECT max(datum) as maxDate
   FROM Skirms 
   WHERE ID = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT max(datum) as maxDate
   FROM Deelnemers
   WHERE skirms_fk = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT max(datum) as maxDate
   FROM Reacties
   WHERE skirms_fk = 1
 ) AS dt
```